# "Build Project" command in RStudio does not show LaTeX equations in HTML output

Tags: latex, rstudio, bookdown

When I use "Build Book" in Rstudio to convert the index.Rmd file -- in Yihui Xie's bookdown-demo.proj project -- into its Bookdown HTML version, Rstudio's HTML viewer shows the $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ LaTeX equation in index.Rmd as \(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\) in Rstudio's HTML viewer. Rstudio's HTML viewer is not displaying the equation the way LaTeX is supposed to show it.

I have installed tinytex, and I have downloaded the latest versions of R and Rstudio (December 24, 2018). Rstudio does display LaTeX equations properly when I use knitr to compile Rmd files that have LaTeX equations in them. But the bookdown project is not doing it right.